# Bone Constraint Copy Scale on multiple bones in chain bug?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I'm trying to make a chain of 8 parented bones stretch on the y axis using the copy scale constraint and a separate controller bone, but using it with more than two bones causes all the parented bones to scale infinitely. Logically, this doesn't make sense. if the controlling bone is scaled to 2, all the bones in the chain should be at a scale of 2. Is this a bug or am I missing something with parenting?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't know about the inherited parenting, disabling that fixed the problem

Comment: You could turn this into an answer that would be more helpful to others it you add some more details. Example: what is inherited parenting. Where to find this setting.